# Low power: how to power a small dc motor from a logic low

Tags: dc-motor, solar-cell, low-power

I have made a circuit to power a small motor with solar cells that I have salvaged from garden led lights. The goal of the circuit is to power the motor everytime the sun has moved a little bit.
My problem is the following: I want to adapt the voltage a the end of the circuit shown bellow in order to drive a motor when the output voltage of the circuit (Vout) is at a low logic value ~250mV and it shouldn't be powered when the output voltage is high ~8V. I thought about using a pMos, but I am not sure, it will be able to drive the motor. Can someone tell me what type of transistor I should use to do that ?
Here is a rough sketch of the circuit: [image]
The last element I have to add is a drive for the dc motor that inverts the low level voltage into a high voltage at the output of the circuit to drive the motor and that is low power.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Misha

Comment: Can you provide more details on your problem? You can drive your motor low side if you drive it with a low, but I'm not sure I understand your issue.

Comment: I'm also confused from reading the text. I think more time spent in writing a better question would go a long way.

Comment: Hello Julien, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the opamp is not able to output enough current to power the motor. As such, I do not think that it is possible to power it low side

Comment: Are you asking how to design a drive for a small motor?

Comment: Hello Periblepsis, I reformulated the question a little bit, I hope it is clearer. Basically, I want to use the output of the opamp shown above  that has two different possible voltage output values ~250mV and ~8V and use it in order to drive a dc motor. When the output voltage of the opamp is low, I would like the motor to turn and when it is high, I would like it to stay still

Comment: Yes Julien, design a drive that is very low power and that inverts the logic levels at the input

Comment: If the op amp hasn't the current to drive the motor then have it drive the base of an NPN bipolar transistor. A big one. I'm assuming you're looking for a logic on/off solution. Motor on when logic low, motor off when logic high.

Comment: You're using the opamp as a comparator, so you can swap the inverting and non-inverting inputs to give you an active high output instead. Then just use that to control a NPN BJT or N-Channel MOSFET to drive your motor.

Comment: does the motor turn when connected to the solar cells directly?

Comment: No the motor doesn't turn when connected to the solar cells, it loads a capacitor that discharges inside the motor from time to time

Answer (score 1):

Pulling together a few comments from others and general recommendations:

As @Julien mentioned, use a comparator instead of a general purpose opamp to do the threshold detection.  Swap the inputs like @brhans said to get an active-high output and use a N-channel MOSFET on the low side to keep the voltage sag on the positive rail from causing any weird behavior.  R1 limits gate current; a gate pull-down resistor shouldn't be necessary in this circuit.  R6 depends on your zener; circuit lab was getting buggier and buggier so I had to cut my losses.

R2 incorporates hysteresis into the circuit so your motor isn't turning on and off rapidly at the crossover point.  Experiment with the value...maybe 100k to start and drop it if you're still seeing rapid switching instead of a single clean transition.

Suppress your motor's coil with a diode.

Replace whatever's going on with R3 and R4 with a potentiometer to dial in the transition point; the absolute value isn't critical; higher values will reduce the leakage current.  For that matter, let's bump up R3 and R4 to reduce the 2mA drain to something a bit lower.  You could probably even go higher than that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSuI8z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: you forgot to draw a connection, top of D1

Comment: Should be fixed, thanks.  CircuitLab was bugging pretty hard with the multiple revisions.

Comment: If the comparator has an open drain/collector output (most do), you will need a pull-up resistor there.

Answer (score 0):

Using your comments, here is what I think you need.
First, you want a comparator to create a real logic signal. You can use an opamp or a comparator (I'd use a comparator) that will drive something like an H bridge. If your motor don't need to turn both side, you can use only one of the branch of the H bridge. For transistor selection, I can't give you a specific recommendation, but I'd use a N channel Mosfet on the lower side.